# like a basic calculator how can i loop this

Tags: python

```
op = input("enter operator: ")
ops = ("+", "-", "*", "/")
if op not in ops:
    print("invalid operator")
    exit()

num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))

num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)

elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)

elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)

elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    op = input("enter operator: ")
    ops = ("+", "-", "*", "/")
    if op not in ops:
        print("invalid operator")
        exit()

    num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))

    num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))

    if op == "+":
        print(num1 + num2)

    elif op == "-":
        print(num1 - num2)

    elif op == "/":
       print(num1 / num2)

    elif op == "*":
        print(num1 * num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a while-loop. Your exit call will automatically end the whole thing.

```
while True:
    
    op = input("enter operator: ")
    ops = ("+", "-", "*", "/")
    if op not in ops:
        print("invalid operator")
        exit()
    
    num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))
    
    if op == "+":
        print(num1 + num2)
    
    elif op == "-":
        print(num1 - num2)
    
    elif op == "/":
        print(num1 / num2)
    
    elif op == "*":
        print(num1 * num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything in a `while True:`.

For users to quit the apllication you can check the input to be equal to 'q' and so you can `break` out of the `while`.

In summary

```py
while True:
  
   # your code
   if op == 'q':
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure but this should work in python > 3.6:

```
print(eval(f'{num1}{op}{num2}'))
```

To verify it check before that num1 and num2 are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

For looping simply user `while True:` with a conditional `break` or `exit()` statement to avoid infinitely loop

**SUGGESTION:**

For making a calculator you can simply use `eval()` method to make your code short and simple.

```
while True:
    op = input('Enter the operator:      ')
    if op not in ['+', '-', '*', '/']:
        print('Quiting...')
        exit()

    ip1 = input('Enter the first Number:  ')
    ip2 = input('Enter the second Number: ')

    print('Answer is : ', eval(f'{ip1}{op}{ip2}'), end='\n----------------------------\n')
```

or simply use eval for taking mathematical expression and give result

```
while True:
    try:
        print('Answer : ', eval(input('Enter your expression : ')), end='\n----------------------------\n')
    except:
        print('Invalid Input\nQuiting...')
        quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use while True and instead of using exit() you can use an else to tell if op is invalid

while True:

```
op = input("enter operator: ")
ops = ("+", "-", "*", "/")
  
num1 = int(input("enter first number: "))
  
num2 = int(input("enter second number: "))

if op == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)

elif op == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)

elif op == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)

elif op == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
else:
    print("invalid operator")
```

and also you can use eval() it makes everything easier

```
cal = input()#Enter the whole equation ("12+10)
print(eval(cal))#22
```

and you're done